# Install touchpad for Kubuntu

Tags: apt, kubuntu, xorg, touchpad

So, my notebook touchpad click is not working after fresh install of Kubuntu 18.04. I know that I need to install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics but when I tried to install it, it gives error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics : Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Then, I tried to install xserver-xorg-core as mentioned but it want to remove a lot of packages.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  xfonts-100dpi | xfonts-75dpi
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  sddm xorg xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xserver-xorg-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 17 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1.351 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7.393 kB disk space will be freed.
```

In my previous installation, I removed all these packages and then I couldn't get into my dekstop environment. Only terminal and if I installed sddm, the keyboard is not working. I need to use usb boooting and chroot to my notebook and install xserver-xorg-input.

Is there any proper way to install the package so that the touchpad is working properly? Thank you.

Comment: If you really have a fresh install, you shouldn't be seeing "This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming."

Comment: I really just download iso for Kubuntu 18.04. I am confused why installing xserver-xorg-input-synaptics need to remove other packages.

Comment: Also, users of Dell laptops are finding that the update to kernel 4.15.0-72 prevents their touchpad from working. Using the previous kernel (kernel 4.15.0-70) is fine.

Comment: I think I am using the latest kernel because I just apt upgrade.

Comment: Please don't install this package for now. Attach an external mouse and use that or try the older kernel if indeed the kernel issue is to blame.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by installing xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04 instead of only xserver-xorg-input-synaptics.

Looking at the package description (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xserver-xorg-input-synaptics),xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is a virtual package that point to xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04. I don't exactly know what happened and why installing xserver-xorg-input-synaptics needs to remove a lot of things from my PC but xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04 works normal.